# Is a business associate agreement available from Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms, encryption

I see that Cognito Forms is now offering data encryption for form entries. Is a business associate agreement available as well?

Answer (score 1):

First, our data security policies are detailed in our help documentation: https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/74/entries/data-security

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) now allows PII to be stored in Cognito Forms as long as full entry encryption is enabled and fields containing sensitive information is marked as protected so we can ensure that this information is not transmitted insecurely through email or web-hooks.

Even with this additional level of encryption we still prohibit the collection of credit card information, especially since we offer both Stripe and PayPal for secure payment and have additional measures to protect this data when payment transactions occur.

In terms of HIPAA, we are evaluating the guidelines for compliance and refining our documentation for internal procedures relevant to this.  It is our intention to provide business associate agreements for our customers once we feel we have full addressed, through this documentation, every provision included in this set of laws.

We already have an executed business associate agreement with Microsoft for the hosting of Cognito Forms in Azure, and Microsoft provides all of the physical and most of the software-based security measures necessary to comply.  We have now added both "encryption at rest" and a means to "protect" fields to prevent insecure transmission to help our customers be compliant.  Now we just need to wade through all of the process/procedure requirements and make sure everything is documented so we can make this available to our customers.